# store variable and a string together inside another php variable

Tags: php, variables, sass

I am trying to store a sass variable inside a php variable, problem is both are declared with prepended $ sign thus confusing php parser . Some thing like this:

```
$color = "$brandColor:#".$_POST["value"].";";
```

Output is:

Notice: Undefined variable: brandColor in C:\xampp\htdocs\sassy\function.php on line 12

Comment: what value is storing in your $brandColor ?

Comment: $brandcolor actually tries to store the value of $brandcolor when you use the double quotes so if it contains 4 you would be trying to create $color as 4:# etc.

Comment: Or use escape slash: $color = "\$brandColor:#".$_POST["value"].";";

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$color = '$brandColor:#'.$_POST["value"].';';
```

Comment: @Daedalus, no it's not the same, the quotes have changed meaning that the variable `$brandColor` will be literally outputted now.

Answer (score 0):

try using single quotes ' instead of double quotes "

Comment: thanks for the instruction. but in fact i think i did provide the answer. after replacing the " by ' it works.